# Accessing FastAPI dependency in a test

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi

The below router endpoint has a dependency on a function that returns an AsyncClient which is then used for calling an external API.

```
async def get_client():
    try:
        client = httpx.AsyncClient()
        yield client

    finally:
        await client.aclose()


@router.get("/testendpoint")
async def get(
    http_req: fastapi.Request,
    client: httpx.AsyncClient = fastapi.Depends(get_client),
):
    return await call_external_api(client)


async def call_external_api(client: httpx.AsyncClient):
    return client.get("https://testapi/data")
```

If I create a test for this endpoint, the dependency will be included (or I can override it using app.dependency_overrides) but I cannot see how to reference the dependency to test that it is passed through to the call_external_api function:

```
api_client = TestClient(app)

def test_get(mocker: pytest_mock.MockFixture):
    mock_func = mocker.patch("call_external_api")
    response = api_client.get("router/testendpoint")
    mock_func.assert_called_once_with(client)  # client here does not exist
```

How can a dependency be referenced in tests, to check it is used correctly downstream of the router endpoint?

Comment: When you're using `dependency_overrides` you control what is being returned - that would be your `reference` client. However, to have less brittle tests, it might be more sensible to just assert that `get` is called on your fake client, instead of having to assume that `call_external_client` etc gets called. In that case you're tying your tests _very closely_ to the implementation, instead of the end result (the call being made). Changing code that have the same end result shouldn't usually require changing the tests as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below mock In test_get(), Use [MockClass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class) from unittest.mock

```
mock_cli = mocker.Mock(spec=httpx.AsyncClient).
```

And Add dependencies to lambda

```
response = api_client.get("router/testendpoint", dependencies=[Depends(lambda: mock_cli)])
```

This can add the dependency to be referenced in tests.

And then you can assert the *mock_cli*

Answer (score 1):

You can mock both the call_external_api and the dependency like so:

```
import pytest

api_client = TestClient(app)


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "fastapi_dep",
    [
        (
            app,
            {get_client: "my object"},
        )
    ],
    indirect=True,
)
def test_get(mocker, fastapi_dep):
    mock_func = mocker.patch(
        "pytest_fastapi_deps.q75695015.call_external_api", return_value="20"
    )
    response = api_client.get("/router/testendpoint")
    mock_func.assert_called_once_with("my object")
```

Note: this code uses [pytest-fastapi-deps](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-fastapi-deps/) which is a library I created for pytest to override the FastApi dependencies.